# sed command how to exclude numeric and dot

Tags: sed

I have file with below contents. Here I am trying to exclude some characters from the beginning of every line.

```
1.apple
2.orange
3.cucumber
4.Cherry
5.mango
lemon
```

From this file I need to exclude all the numeric and dot(.), then I need to print all the lines from the file.

```
sed -n '/[0-5.]/!p' file
```

**Output :**

```
lemon
```

Because this will excluded all the number between `0-5` and printed only word `lemon` from the file.

But I need to extract all the numbers and dot using `sed` command ?

**Output Required :**

```
apple
orange
cucumber
Cherry
mango
```

could you please someone help me on this ?

Comment: Your last required output doesn't have `lemon`. Is it fine ? Or Is it typo ?

Answer (score 3):

***sed*** approach:

```
sed 's/^[0-9]\.//' file
```

---

- `^` - the beginning of the line (anchor)
- `[0-9]` - range of numbers
- `\.` - matches `.` character literally, should be escaped with `\` according to its special meaning

---

The output (as you wrote: *"I need to print **all** the lines from the file"*):

```
apple
orange
cucumber
Cherry
mango
lemon
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you want like this ?

With `sed`:

```
sed -n 's/^[0-9]\.//p' file
```

Output:

```
$ sed -n 's/^[0-9]\.//p' file
apple
orange
cucumber
Cherry
mango
```

Comment: I was tried without escaping spacial character also "sed -n 's/^[0-9].//p' file" it is working fine.

Comment: @user6420577, Glad it worked for you. If you didn't escape the dot, then it will consider as regex ( In regex `.` means any one character (not literal dot character ). For ex: `echo "5@mango" | sed -n 's/^[0-9].//p'`

Comment: If this answer helped you solve your problem, I suggest that you "Accept" this answer (by clicking the check mark).

Comment: Thanks lot again Your way of presentation very nice with echo command.

Answer (score 0):

sed  's/^ *[0-9]+.//g' yourfile > newfile

this will work for any range of numbers.
Try this.